# asp.net webapi POST works on Postman, but not in browser AJAX request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

My asp.net HttpPost test applicantion is working fine in Postman, but it returns error in HTML AJAX request.

My controller:

```
public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody] myData m)
    {
        return String.Format("Test A");
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class myData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

If I run the request in Postman with the URL: http://localhost:52884/api/contact and the body:

```
{ 
    "FirstName" : "FName", 
    "LastName" : "LName" 
}
```

It runs fine! I see the output: "Test A"

However, when I try it with HTML Ajax request:

```
    <html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "http://localhost:52884/api/contact",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { FirstName: "FName", LastName: "LName" },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                console.debug(xhr);
                var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
                if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                    err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I see in the console the error:

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:52884/api/contact?callback=jQuery112409902197956907268_1507917530625&FirstName=FName&LastName=LName&_=1507917530626”.
```

Comment: Please, change **`dataType: 'jsonp'`** to **`dataType: "json"`**.

Comment: you are using jsonp but there is no callback in your code. Have you tried using `JSON.stringyfy({ FirstName: "FName", LastName: "LName" })`

Comment: which version of web api are you using? have you set the default return value in json format in config file?

Comment: No, it is not working. Try to call your index.html from a file outside the Visual Studio project.

Comment: If I remove jsonp I got CORS error

Comment: @user6824563: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good night!

You need use JSON.stringfy in your object, against { FirstName: "FName", LastName: "LName"}

See example:

const data = { FirstName: "FName", LastName: "LName"}
const jsonData = JSON.stringfy(data);

url: "http://localhost:52884/api/contact",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: jsonData, //{ FirstName: "FName", LastName: "LName" },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },

I hope I can help you.